# Mapping of some Data in c#

Tags: c#, list, mapping

i search for a good solution for mapping data in c#.
At first i have a Character "a" and a angle "0.0" degree.
What is the best solution for the Mapping ? A list ?

One requirement is that i must search for the degree if it not in the "list" then i add a new one.. and so on

thanks for help :)

**EDIT: I must find out if the angle exists ! If the angle not exists then add a new char**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionary< double,char>

Example:

```
Dictionary< double, char> dic = new Dictionary< double, char>();
//Adding a new item
void AddItem(char c, double angle)
{
    if (!dic.ContainsKey(angle))
        dic.Add(angle,c);
}
//Retreiving an item
char GetItem(double angle)
 {
    char c;
    if (!dic.TryGetValue(angle, out c))
        return '';
    else
        return c;   
 }
```

Comment: but char, double must be double, char

Comment: how can i get the char for specific double ? and u must fix: void AddItem(double angle, char c, Dictionary<double, char> dic)

Comment: I assume that you use this code inside a class and dic is a member of that class so you don't need to reference it in every function.

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary.

```
var d =new Dictionary<string,double> ()`
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary should be fine:

```
Dictionary<string, float> dict = new Dictionary<string, float>();
dict.Add("a", 0.0);
float angle = dict["a"]
if( !dict.Contains("b"))
{
  dict["b"] = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: In the question he wants to search by angles, not characters, so angle should be the key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `SortedDictionary`.?

```
 private SortedDictionary<string, double> _myStuff;

...

if (!_myStuff.ContainsValue(0))
...
```

Answer (score -1):

[Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) looks to be the thing you are looking for. Make the degree as the Hashkey and you can search it later quite easily.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
if (!ht.ContainsKey(angle))
    ht.Add(key, value);
```

Comment: after that i can search for an character to specific angle ? thx

Comment: your answer is correct in general but for this specific problem where the user wants a "char" key, the hashtable introduces unnedeed overhead and space requirements because it always hashes the key.

Comment: In .NET 2.0 and above you should really be using Dictionary(TKey, TValue)- see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: u mean:
Dictionary< double, char > dic = new Dictionary< double , char>();
...
void AddItem(double angle, char c)
{
    if (!dic.ContainsKey(angle))
        dic.Add(angle, c);
}
but how can i get the c to angle ?